# Is there a function for creating 3D objects/ellipsoids with color transparency changing depending on radius from the center (using python/matplotlib)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

hopefully this is not a repeat question. I am currently trying to plot 3D ellipsoids and create a darkness gradient within the ellipsoid, where the color is darkest at the center of the ellipsoid and becomes lighter as you go further away from the center. My current method is to use matplotlib and to plot multiple ellipsoids using ax.plot_surface and a for loop. In essence, I increment the radius by some factor and plot larger and larger ellipsoids sequentially. Then by manipulating the alpha value of the surfaces, I can overlay the ellipsoids and create a gradient effect, where the interior of the ellipsoid appears darker than the exterior layers. However, I feel like this method has some limitations, and am looking to see if there is a better way. Does anyone have any ideas?

Note: In this case, I do not believe colormaps are useful for my visualization. I think the best example of what I would like my plots to look like is something like an electron cloud, with an ellipsoid with a solid interior and the transparency increasing as the radius increases.

Comment: No.  The 3D functionalities of matplotlib are quite limited.  Matplotib's [3D faq](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html) suggests checking out [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/).

Comment: Would you have any suggestions on what to do in Mayavi? I see that there is the plot3d functions but it still seems like it has a similar limitation in that it only plots the exterior surface, rather than the entire volume of the ellipsoid.

Comment: I don't know much about Mayavi. But what you're describing sounds quite heavy.  Did you see the [chemistry example](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_chemistry.html#example-chemistry)? Otherwise, maybe some custom programming in a 3D engine such [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) will be needed (Blender supports scripting in Python).